# Remote Desktop Services Manager constantly refreshes

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows

Title pretty much sums it up. I'm using the Remote Desktop Services Manager snap in in Windows 7 to view a list of users logged in to a collection of 5 Windows 2003 terminal servers. The list of users refreshes nearly constantly. This happens if I view them through the "My Group" view, or by server.

I've changed the options to refresh with a longer delay, and even set the console to wait until I manually refresh, but neither setting seems to make a difference. I only have this problem in Windows 7, XPs console didn't have this problem.

Thoughts ? I'm not primary support for these servers so I don't have a lot of detail, but I'll be happy to provide any more relevant details if asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll probably see RDP listeners being created and destroyed in rapid fashion. These are external users trying to "hack" in to the RDP server by submitting a brute force username/password connection to the server.

Comment: Would there be a more legitimate reasons for these listeners being rapidly created/destroyed ?

Comment: I can't think of one. Can you see if what I described is in fact what is occurring?

Comment: I've brought this up but not gotten any response from the admin team. Either way I appreciate your input joequerty.

Comment: Glad to help...